# Using "setImageBitmap" and center image to point

Tags: android

I have a `Dialog box` that has a `Bitmap` image and two points to it. I am setting the `Image` to a `View` using `setImageBitmap()`. This works fine but I what I am looking to do is re-centre the `Image` to the point that was passed. ie User clicks on the screen and dialog appears with the image but centre of the image is where the user clicked

```
view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
view.setCropToPadding(false);
```

Thanks

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: Nothing really. Cannot find the command (if one exists to do it). 
Did try a matrix but the image did not move